# NLTK tokenizes a quote sentence into two

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, tokenize

Here is the code:

```
x = '"What do you mean?" asked Jack, looking down.'
nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(x)
```

Here is the output:

```
['"What do you mean?"', 'asked Jack, looking down.']
```

What I would like to get:

```
['"What do you mean?" asked Jack, looking down.']
```

I am not sure how to fix the issue, any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using `'sent_tokenize()'` which is creating sentences as tokens. And it observes '?' question-mark and '.' full-stop as end-of sentences, that is why it is creating 2 tokens from your given string.

Read about NLTK tokenizers here - https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html

For your expected output, given the sentence in question, you may do-

```
x.split(',')
```

Comment: I understand this addresses the specific example included in the question, but it does not address the question of how to handle punctuations within quotes when using NLTK. Not sure if this is a good answer even though it was accepted.